# How to map different function signatures into the same std::map?

Tags: c++, function, c++11

I had some issues which were pointed in the comments, so this is my new minimal reproducible code sample;

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
std::string foo(int bar)
{
    return std::to_string(bar); 
}
std::string foo(std::vector<int> bar)
{
    int baz;
    //process
    return foo(baz);
}
std::string foo(std::string bar)
{
    std::vector<int> baz;
    //process
    return foo(baz);
}
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string,std::function<std::string(std::string)>> baz;
    //error baz["foo"]=static_cast<std::function<std::string(std::string)>>(&foo);
    /*working*/baz["foo"]=static_cast<std::string(*)(std::string)>(&foo);
    std::string qux;
    std::cout<<baz["foo"](qux)<<std::endl;
}
```

Given this, I can do what I intend when I static cast `foo` into `baz` like in second way. But why can't it be done in the first way?

What I ask, is that;

```
(<std::function<std::string(std::string)> == std::string(*)(std::string))
```

I thought these two would be equal, but apparently when it comes to static cast, they're not.
Why so?

Also, are these same or not?

```
std::map<std::string,std::function<std::string(std::string)>> baz;
std::map<std::string,std::string(*)(std::string)> baz;
```

And why?

Comment: You can't have two `foo(std::string)` with different return types.

Comment: @Jarod42 I know, but I need `foo()`s to be different on both return type and argument list.

Comment: @Jarod42 My overloads compile well, that's not the problem. Problem is, they all can't be static cast with all their different signatures into the same map. Because they will be auto-generated with _fold expressions_.

Comment: @Jarod42 And I need a way around...

Comment: If you type-erase all the functions (pointers) stored in the map, how will you then call them?

Comment: `std::pair<int,int> foo(std::string)`, `std::string foo(std::string)` is problematic (first snippet).

Comment: @Jarod42 And I actually have one `foo(std::string)` and that is the side-function of all `foo()`s.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, that's another problem. I'm still thinking about it. Maybe a complicated switch-case would do, but one problem at a time. I'll think about it after this one is solved, if possible.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)...

Comment: If your problem comes from using fold expressions and parameter packs, then your question should include the code demonstrating that problem. Here, you've provided code for one thing, but you say your problem is something else. And your "fix" is confusing; you're not storing multiple values in a single map slot. You're storing one value, and then you're replacing it with another. It looks like you want to store many different overloads into the same map value. Maybe you want a multimap?

Comment: @DanielLangr I'm doing these to understand further what can be done and what can't be done with C++, so these may all seem theoretical.

Comment: `f1["foo"]=[](auto... args)( return foo(args...));` might handle overloads, but then you cannot find type to extract from `std::any`...

Comment: @RobKennedy How will `std::multimap` handle this?

Comment: Multimap lets you store multiple values under a single key, which appears to be what you want by your multiple assignments to `f1["foo"]`. Did I misunderstand your example code?

Comment: @RobKennedy Either way, function signatures differ. So what will be the `mymultimap.second`s type?

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried to use your solution but it didn't compile. Can you give me a simple working example please?

Comment: @Xemdocia Mapped type of multimap would be `std::any`, the same as for ordinary map.

Comment: `std::multimap<std::string, std::any>`, same as you already have. Or, if you have a fixed list of overloads, maybe you just need to define a class with all those methods. Then use `std::map<std::string, that_class>` and you don't have to worry about unresolved overloads because you're not directly assigning function pointers anymore. It wouldn't solve any problems with folding and parameter packs, but I don't know the details of _that_ problem.

Comment: @RobKennedy I see, thanks for your help. I'll try it and it surely will solve few things.

Comment: @Xemdocia: "*See my edit down below please*" Please integrate edits into your post; don't tell people to start at the bottom if there's some vital information there. Make your post read as if you had put that information where it belonged originally.

Comment: What do you intend to be done by the line `f1["foo"]=foo;`? Which `foo` function are you trying to assign to `f1["foo"]`? (You cannot assign both at once since they are distinct functions even though they happen to share a name. That's probably where your cast comes in -- it tells the compiler which function to use, similar to how the arguments in a call to `foo` would determine which function with that name to call.)

Comment: @JaMiT I intend to map all overloads of `foo()` to be mapped under `f1["foo"]` so when `f1["foo"]` is called, it should automatically be decided on which overload of `foo()` to call.

Comment: @JaMiT I'll give my recent sample in few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the comments correctly, the `std::map<Key, Value>` is only part of the problem. You first need the `Value` part - what C++ type can hold the overload set of `f`?

Jarod's comment is right: You basically need `[](auto... args){ return foo(args...)};`. This is a single lambda object, with an overloaded `operator()`. Each overload of `operator()` selects one of your `foo()` overloads.

This then shows the ultimate problem. `[](auto... args){ return bar(args...)};` is another lambda, with a different type, so it can't go in the same `std::map<Key, Value>`.

That's really no surprise. When the compiler sees `baz["foo"](qux)`, it needs `Value::operator(std::string)`. That can be a template instantiation, but an instantiation cannot happen at runtime. So `Value` can't depend on `"foo"`. C++ simply does not have run-time overloading, that is not how the language works.

@JesperJuhl may have a point that this is an XY problem. What if you had `foo(std::variant<int, std::string, std::vector<int>>)` ? This is not an overload set; this is a single function. Behind the scenes, it can dispatch to `foo_impl(...)` in any way you like.

Comment: Thank you, this solves everything. I even tried to use _fold expressions_ and _parameter packs_ to emulate **runtime overloading**. I just didn't know the name of what I was trying to do and that it can't be done.

Comment: How can it be dispatched like that? I'm trying to think of something useful but I'm out of ideas now.

Comment: @Xemdocia: `switch` on `std::variant<int, std::string, std::vector<int>>::index`. If that's 0, the variant holds an `int`, if 1 a `std::string`, if 2 a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try that later in today.